# Remove .php in files (redirect user to custom 404 page if such file does not exist) in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Please i need a quick fix,

I have completed a site and I use `.htaccess` to rewrite the urls to remove `.php` with my intention for only known files i.e. if I have `about.php` then I can have `/about` it worked fine with the following `.htaccess` lines

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Now I created another line to handle custom `404` error

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Now here is the problem, I get `500 Internal Server Error` upon navigating to unknown files instead of redirecting to 404....

Apache rewriting is somehow wield so i just dont have the time now, any help please

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

Well you should be able to go to the page without the .php, so if you have like a header file or config file, just put this code up top after session stuff. You can remove the rewrite rule.

```
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -4) === '.php') {
    require '404.php';
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Would just expand on info a bit more.. So its improving the routing rather than a catch all in the .htaccess.

Comment: So where is the header file, I am not using framework, I just want to redirect and remove the .php in front of files and send other to 404.... so this in my opinion will not work as i have to do something like routing all request to a file and constructing a router system from that file... I dont have time for that, the work is completed already